# RequestTooLargeError: The request to API call datastore_v3.Put() was too large

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, memory-leaks

I am getting the error:

```
The request to API call datastore_v3.Put() was too large.
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~app-prod/version/controllers/app/file.py", line 470, in function_name
temp_o.put()
RequestTooLargeError: The request to API call datastore_v3.Put() was too large.
```

for the following code:

```
temp_o = models.Temp.all().get()
temp_o.list = json.dumps(temp_list)
temp_o.put()
```

When I get the size of temp_o.list using the following code:

```
logging.info('size of list = %s', sys.getsizeof(temp_o.list))
```

The result I get is:

```
size of list = 4241156
```

Since sys.getsizeof() returns value in bytes, so this is only 4.2 MB. Why would saving only 4.2 MB data lead to RequestTooLargeError in Google App Engine?

Comment: Because the limit is 1mb per entity, so yeah, 4.2mb is too large

Answer (score 3):

This is due to 1MB limit on max entity size. In my case temp_o.list is a TextProperty. See [cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore](http://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore) (scroll to the bottom of the page)